# Can the "To:" field in the SendObject be set Dynamically per Combo box selection?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using a form where I have a combo box which get populated by user. I also have a button to send an email with a attached report.

My problem is that I want to set the value of the "To:" field within the SendObject with the value which is in the Combo Box in my form.

Can we dynamically set the "To:" field in the SendObject ?

Comment: Yes. Simply supply the value of the appropriate combobox column e.g. `Me.YourCombo.Column(1)` to the `sendobject` method. If you post what you have so far and the function & location of the function from which you are evaluating the `sendobject` method, we can assist you more accurately.

Comment: @lee mac thank you, this is what I have at the moment :     
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "YTD-", acFormatXLS, "'*" & Me.Filter3 & "*'@companyname.com", , , "YTD Commission Statement-'*" & Me.Filter3 & "*'", "Attached please find the YTD Commission Statement."

Comment: I think I need help with syntax, because it is currently showing the combo box value, but not taking the "@companyname.com" into account in the 'to:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided in your comments, I would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```vb
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "YTD-", acFormatXLS, _
Me.Filter3 & "@companyname.com", , , _
"YTD Commission Statement-" & Me.Filter3, _
"Attached please find the YTD Commission Statement."
```

Comment: Thank you @Lee Mac, I am going to give it a try in a few hours here, and post the update.

Comment: Works great! Thank you